# How do I transform an imageview transition for a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an xml layout that is a lineary layout. Inside this linearlayout, I have a small fragment that I want to slide in from the left if the user swipes from left to right, and right to left when the user swype from right to left making the fragment disappear. I was using an imageview originally so the code for that was

```
Animation slideInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyZonesActivity.this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
                    imgLayer2.startAnimation(slideInAnimation);
                    imgLayer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I've tried searching for this on stack overflow but everyone was using a base fragment under their fragment and I couldn't get their examples to work

Comment: How do you add the fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a FrameLayout which you place your original content in.

When user swipes, you will add your fragment in that layout with a fragment transaction having set the animation of the transaction to slide_in_left. That means that the fragment will appear above the previous view since its the upper element of the FrameLayout and because you set the animation to slide_in_left it will appear by sliding left.

If you set the animationout of the transaction to be slide_out_left then when you pop backstack of fragment manager the view will slide out left.

You can catch the slide geture and pop the bacstack manually.